# Multiple selection if some form option are selected

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I want to make a dynamic filter system based on a html form with multiple options, some like that:

```
<form>
  <select>
  <option></option>
  -//-
  </select>
  <select>
  <option></option>
   --//--
   </select>
</form>
```

and make a sql query but with condition from form, and every option have an "All" option which means no condition.
So i was thinking to make something like that, with multiple for and N^2 if condition, but is to much code and it's not faster... to make 16 if-uri and 16 SELECT for a 4 option form ... 
So, know someone a faster solution ? 
Thanks.
Edit 
So let say i have a database users with ID, Name, Age, City.
I make a form with 3 option (1 for Name, 1 for Age, 1 for City) so i can see only some users, let say i want all users which have name Nick and it's from Miami.
I need to my SELECT condition to exclude the condition for AGE, like now select will be :
`Select * from Users where Name = 'Nick' and City='Miami'`
, but if i want to see users with Age= 18 and City NY my select will need to exclude the condition for Name, and be like:
 `Select * from Users where Age= 18 and City='NY'`.

Comment: your question is not clear.can you add some more informations to it?

Comment: Explain requirement properly with example.

Comment: You can just check database fields with select-option, but for values like age=18, city="NY" you need textbox elements in form. It will not work using select-option.

Comment: was random example, let's say will be <option value='18'>18</option>, and more like this.